# Redirect changing url but not rendering components

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

i am trying to make a redirect work using `props.history.push`.

When i do that it changes the URL to the set location, but the component where it gets redirected from still gets rendered and the new component to which it is redirected to doesn't. I've noticed this happens when i move my `Router` to the `index.js` file from `App.js`. I even used `withRouter` for App. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

- App.js

```js
  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <Switch location={location} key={location.key}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
        ...
        <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      </Switch>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

export default withRouter(App);
```

- index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <GlobalContextProvider>
        <App />
      </GlobalContextProvider>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Can someone please tell me if i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Where do you have code which fires the redirect itself?

Comment: i have it in the useEffect hook to fire once . `props.history.push('/login')`

Comment: If you are using react router maybe try to use Hook version: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Comment: which hook are you referring to?